# Second method for getting output using SQL query in ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which has data as:

[image]

My expected output is:

[image]

I got my expected output as using rownum:

```
SELECT ID,PRICE FROM OT.TEST1 WHERE ROWNUM<3;
```

It's working finesince i have inserted the data serially as the output is coming with rownum ,but what,if the data were inserted as random below,my rownum will not work.Is there any new method?

```
ID PRice
3  300
3  600
8  600
2  600
```

Comment: The query you posted is only guaranteed to return an arbitrary 2 rows-- any 2 rows would be equally valid.  If you want to return a specific 2 rows, you'd need to tell us which rows you want to return.  I have no idea how you determined that you wanted (3,300) and (2,600) to be returned rather than either of the other two rows.

Comment: Table data is considered unordered. It is left to chance which two rows you get with `WHERE ROWNUM < 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRICE, ID) rn
    FROM OT.TEST1 t
)

SELECT ID, PRICE
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Here we are assigning a row number over the entire table ordered first by price ascending, and then by `ID`.  Since three records are tied for a price of 600, the record with the lowest `ID` would happen to be returned here.